# Filter AlertLevel to Faill Build - Jenkins + OWASP ZAP Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, owasp, zap

Actually i'm integrating Jenkins with ZAP Docker but the Job failure is quite binary (always fail or always pass with "-I" parameter). I'm using:

- Jenkins Declarative Pipeline wrote with groovy.
- ZAP Docker from official repository

I would like to know if there some parameter when execute scan through docker command to Break Jenkins Job only if the result is a High or Critical vulnerability. Maybe using the Input function of Jenkins Pipeline to provide a manual interaction with user.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline snippets here?